# can I get whether a field has been assigned with reflection in golang

Tags: go, reflection

I have a struct as below:

```
type Demo struct{
     A string
     B string
}
```

and I have a instance of it as below:

```
demo := Demo{A:"a"}
```

the field of **A** has been assigned value explicit but field **B** not.
Now, I want to know are there exist some method that I can get the field of Instance **A** which has been **assigned** value through **reflection**?

Here I want to get field **A**.

Comment: Do you want to get the value of the field, the name of the field or both?

Comment: @ThunderCat I want to know whether a field has been assigned value. Here field `A` has been assigned value but `B` not.

Comment: @ThunderCat     a boolean reporting that some field is assigned

Comment: "but field B not". This statement is **wrong**! B was assigned the value "", the zero value for a string. There _are_ _no_ unassigned values in Go.

Comment: @Volker yeah. Strictly speaking，I want to get the field which assigned value explicit rather than zero value by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to determine if a field was explicitly assigned a value, but it is possible to determine if there's a field that's not equal to the field's zero value.

Loop through the fields. Return true if a field's value is not equal to the zero value for the field's type.

```
func hasNonZeroField(s interface{}) bool {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(s)
    if v.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        v = v.Elem()
    }
    t := v.Type()
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        sf := t.Field(i)
        fv := v.Field(i)
        switch sf.Type.Kind() {
        case reflect.Chan, reflect.Func, reflect.Interface, reflect.Map, reflect.Ptr, reflect.Slice:
            if !fv.IsNil() {
                return true
            }
        case reflect.Struct:
            if hasNonZeroField(fv.Interface()) {
                return true
            }
        // case reflect.Array:
        // TODO: call recursively for array elements
        default:
            if reflect.Zero(sf.Type).Interface() != fv.Interface() {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cRNBPtuErTO).

Comment: it worked, but as for some specific type like array, it yield  panic:  runtime error: comparing uncomparable type []*xx .